# Apps for windows 8 tablet?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tablet

I'm developing an app for tablet picture capturing. I want to use the windows store app.

I don't want to publish it. Can I develop it without publishing it to the store?

Any other ideas for app dev?

Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "please give me ideas for an app" site. Certainly you can do some research yourself about whether you can develop without the app store. Have you tried looking first? SO should be the *last resort* for problems after you've made a substantial effort to solve them yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can develop a Windows Store app with publishing it but you will be the only one who can use it.  If you want someone else to run your app they would have to use your code in VS on their machine to run it.

Comment: but if I don't want anybody to use it, it's not accessible to others UNLESS I publish it?

Comment: Essentially. For any regular user (not a developer with Windows STore license) to use a Windows Store app that you create it has to be published in the Windows App Store or a company private store.